# CRM 4.0 - KeyListener at associated views

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

i'm working on a MS CRM 4.0 project. In the onLoad of some entity I attach a keypress-event like this:

```
if (document.addEventListener)
   document.addEventListener('keyup', HandleRefreshSignal, false);
else if (document.attachEvent){
   document.attachEvent('onkeyup', HandleRefreshSignal);
```

But this only works, if I have choosen the *Information* in the navigation on the left side when sending a key. If I work in any associated view, the key is ignored.

I've also tried tried to attach the Event to window `(window.attachEvent)`, but there was also no reaction...

Do you have an idea how to fire the keypressevent everytime?

Answer (score 0):

You could try the old fashioned `document.onkeyup = function () { ... }`.

Comment: Thanks, but I still get the same result. Is there a possibility to attach the onkeyup-Event to the associated views?

Comment: I could not find something to enable you to do that, sorry.